# Giving each loop post unique numbers so that Wordpress would treat separately

Tags: loop, javascript, html

So I got this code right now.

The problem I get is that it executes only for the first video.

I know I need to give each loop post a unique number in order for WordPress to treat them separately. Same for my script.

How can I achieve that?

Need help guys!

```
<!-- Autoplay, on view video START-->   
<script>
    const localVideo = document.getElementById('local-video');

    // Play the video when it's in the viewport
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        const rect = localVideo.getBoundingClientRect();
        const windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

        if (rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= windowHeight) {
            localVideo.play();
        } else {
            localVideo.pause();
        }
    });

    // Pause video when page is not visible
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
        if (document.hidden) {
            localVideo.pause();
        } else {
            localVideo.play();
        }
    });
</script>


<!-- Autoplay, on view video END--> 


 <div id="video-container">
        <video id="local-video" loop autoplay controls>
            <source src="<?php echo $video ?>" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>



#video-container {
    width: 360px;
    height: 640px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#local-video {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 360px;
    height: 640px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your `<video>` id to be a class, so that there can be multiple of them on a page.
2. Use `.querySelectorAll('video.local-video')` to get all video elements with the class name of `.local-video`.
3. Loop through all of those elements, and play them accordingly.

Code:

```
<!-- Autoplay, on view video START-->   
<script>
    const localVideos = document.querySelectorAll('video.local-video'); // <= select ALL instances of .local-video

    // Play the video when it's in the viewport
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        localVideos.forEach((video) => { // <= loop through ALL videos and perform your function
            const rect = video.getBoundingClientRect();
            const windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

            if (rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= windowHeight) {
                video.play();
            } else {
                video.pause();
            }
        });
    });

    // Pause video when page is not visible
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
        localVideos.forEach((video) => { // <= also loop here
            if (document.hidden) {
                video.pause();
            } else {
                video.play();
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<!-- Autoplay, on view video END--> 
<div id="video-container">
    <video class="local-video" loop controls>
        <source src="<?php echo $video ?>" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but for some reason it doesn't work. Now all of my videos just autoplay. And doesn't pause when it's not visible.

Is there any other solution? I have been banging my head to the wall all day. Can't make it work...

Comment: @RaymondM Shoot, just realized I didn't change the `<video id=` to `<video class=`. There was also an `autoplay` parameter on the video tag itself, which might be the culprit. Also let me know if you're getting any errors in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @YourManDan . For some reason it didn't work also. But I found the solution that worked.  Thanks a lot for the effort mate, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @RaymondM No problem! Can you post your solution as an answer here and mark it as correct so that if anyone else comes across this problem they can see your work?